# PsychoPy voicekey crashes experiment

Tags: python, psychopy, voice-recording

We are using Psychopy Version 1.83.04 and have created an experiment with vocal responses. We mainly need the reaction time (or latency time) until speech onset.

For that we have introduced the code in "Begin Experiment" in the builder like in the demo "Word naming".

```
Import psychopy.voicekey as vk
vk.pyo_init(rate=44100, buffersize=32)
```

However, the program crashes already somewhere there...

The error feedback after forcing the window to close (there is just a grey screen) is:

> "Server already booted! Assertion failed: framesPerBuffer == Server -> bufferSize, file src/engine/servermodule.c, line 157
>   This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way."

The demo works almost perfectly (just crashes at the very end, but records data...)

Although I was looking, I cannot find what the `buffersize` means and whether there is the cause of the problem?

Comment: The `import` statement should be in lowercase letters. The error message you receive could be due to force-closing the application, thereby unexpectedly destroying the connection with the pyo server. Could you possibly try to create a minimal example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) that demonstrates the problem, compile the script (press F5), and post it here so we can try to replicate it? What platform are you using, anyway (Windows, Mac, Linux)? What error messages do you get when the demo crashes?